# Replacing the first occurrence from the End

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following String: `a-b-b-d`, How can  I replace the first occurrence  of `b` but from **the end of the string**, I use the following **RegEx**: `(b)` to replace the first `b` with `c` so I get `a-c-b-d` And what I want is `a-b-c-d`

What I tried was `(b)*$` but it only works if i removed `-d` from the string.

Comment: You can actually say last if you mean last, it kinda is what that word is for ;-) And you want the `b` that is followed by anything that isn't a b - keyword: negated character class - repeated zero or multiple times, til the end.

Comment: @CBroe last is a flag, correct?

Comment: Easy, use `(.*)b` and replace with `$1`. See https://jsfiddle.net/1zkfb8op/. Another way: `replace(/b([^b]*)$/, '$1')`

Comment: _"last is a flag, correct"_ - no, I simply meant "last" is the easy, convenient, short-hand way the English language has provided us with to say "first but from the end." Sorry if that caused confusion ;-)